# Laravel 'Whoops' error in Public after fresh Install

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I installed Laravel locally on MAMP and navigated to the correct localhost location, and for some reason am getting `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

The route.php looks fine:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Apparently it's caused by this (arrow) in `/bootstrap/compiled.php`:

```
 protected function getJsonPayload($payload)
    {
   ---->      $payload = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);
       if (!$payload || $this->invalidPayload($payload)) {
            throw new DecryptException('Invalid data.');
```

What am I missing in my new install to make this work?

Comment: How did you install Laravel? Also looks like you need to turn debug to true in the config to see what's really going on.

Comment: @DavidBarker Okay just updated the question with the error.

Comment: try `php artisan optimize` to rebuild `compiled.php`

Comment: @DavidBarker I installed via git to a local mamp folder

Comment: In that case, you'll need to run `composer update` to ensure you're getting all the appropriate packages. That *should* also run the `php artisan optimize` (or `dump-autoload`, not sure which). That will ensure that the environment is set up correctly for Laravel.

Comment: Really interesting! @Kryten - I ran update, and now it's getting stuck on a different file - same problem. `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php`

Comment: Maybe it has to do with @user1305626's suggestion below to check the mcrypt extension after all...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57286/discussion-between-itamar-and-kryten).

Answer (score 0):

You should give write permissions (777) to app/storage folder, also try to define debug as true in app/config/app.php to check what is going on.

Comment: Okay I updated the question with the error I'm getting.

Comment: It's very strange, check if you have mcrypt PHP extension installed

Answer (score 0):

You try -> go to url you want-> in here you clear cookie.
if chrome: F12 -> Resources -> Clear Cookies here.